# Pavilion and Envy laptop screens- Compatible?

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, hp-pavilion, hp-envy

So, the screen on my HP Dv7t-7000 quad edition laptop broke, and I'm looking for a replacement. The only thing I can find is [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Genuine-HP-Envy-DV7T-7300-Whole-Screen-Display-Assambly-/172295761458?hash=item281da0ae32:g:x2QAAOSwtnpXpK8V). It looks basically the same, but it's for the dv7t-7300, and says "Envy dv7" in the top corner where mine says "Pavilion dv7". If I purchase this screen, are all the connectors (physical and electrical) compatible with my laptop?

Comment: Question to those voting to close this: Why? It seems to fall within the "good question" bounds as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's not hardware shopping though. I'm simply asking about compatibility between two items. This seems to be within the bounds of questions about "computer hardware"